# Debugging is not working in Ruby-Mine 6.3 with ruby v2.1.1

Tags: debugging, rubymine

I am using ruby v2.1.1p76. I have installed ruby-debug-ide which is the default for RubyMine IDE.But while starting debug, it is showing error as-

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/debugger-1.6.7/ruby_debug.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000058

I have tried debugger-xml gem also but that also crashed.The error log is -

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/debugger-xml-0.3.3/bin/rdebug-ide: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/debugger-1.6.7/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: rb_vm_get_sourceline

In ruby v1.9.3-p385 the debugger is working fine,the issue is only with ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux].Please help...

Thanks
Ansuman

Comment: byebug - is that an option for you? I think it will help

Comment: Please check is there any additional gem in your Gemfile? I had the similar problem and I removed `'pry-debugger'` gem from Gemfile and then it worked fine.